# Custom Regular Expression to Exclude List of Characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a program with a lot of string constants being used to allow specific characters via Regular Expressions. I now have a list of characters I want to block everywhere, but I don't want to have to go back through all my old string constants and rewrite them. Instead, I want to create of list of restricted characters and edit that list in only one place (in case it changes in the future). I'll then run all the string constants through a custom Regular Expression.

I have the list of restricted characters defined in web.config like so:

```
<add key="RestrChar" value="\,!,#,%,&lt;,&gt;,|,&amp;,;"/>
```

Calling a custom regular expression like this:

```
[RestrictCharRegExpress(ConstantStringName, ErrorMessage = CustomErrMsg)]
public string StringName
```

Class is defined as follows:

```
public class RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
   public RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute(string propRegex) : base(GetRegex(propRegex)){ }

   private static string GetRegex(string propRegex)
   {
        string restrictedChars = ConfigureationManager.AppSettings.Get("RestrChar");
        string[] thisCharArray = restrictedChars.Split(',');
        string regexPrep = "";
        foreach (string c in thisCharArray)
        {
            regexPrep = string.Format(@"""{0}""", c);
            propRegex = Regex.Replace(propRegex, regexPrep, "");
        }
        return propRegex;
    }
}
```

But it's not removing the characters like I expect. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why not use string replace instead of regex.  String method is more efficient.and easier to implement in this case.

Comment: For example: So in some of my string constants I might be using the backslash (\) to escape another character but if I use string replace then it might remove backslashes from string constants when that's not what I want it to do. I would only want it to remove backslashes if they are are not being used as Regular Expression Escape Characters. Regex.Replace should be smart enough to differentiate this. String.Replace is not.

Comment: Remove foreach and use `return Regex.Replace(propRegex, $"[{string.Concat(thisCharArray)}]+", "")`. Note you only need to escape `^`, `-`, ``\``, `]` if you use this approach. If you keep them unescaped in the `value`, you may do it in the code: `{string.Concat(thisCharArray.Select(x => x.Replace("\\", @"\\").Replace("]", @"\]").Replace("^", @"\^").Replace("-", @"\-")))}`

Comment: An escape character is an escape character.  Regex doesn't know anything more than string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for that. It seems to be working really well.

Comment: @jdweng Ok my mistake. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I saw that thank you. Mind if I ask another favor? I now have a follow on question posted here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601951/pass-old-regular-expression-pattern-to-new-custom-regular-expression-to-exclude?noredirect=1#comment97900264_55601951) Mind taking a look?

Comment: I saw that one, it is too broad for me. There is no solution if you ask me. You need to reconsider the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove `foreach` and use

```
private static string GetRegex(string propRegex)
{
    string restrictedChars = ConfigureationManager.AppSettings.Get("RestrChar");
    string[] thisCharArray = restrictedChars.Split(',');
    return Regex.Replace(propRegex, 
        $"[{string.Concat(thisCharArray)}]+", "");
}
```

Note you only need to escape `^`, `-`, `\`, `]` if you use this approach.

If you keep them unescaped in the `value`, you may do it in the code:

```
var regex = string.Concat(
        thisCharArray.Select(x => 
            x.Replace("\\", @"\\").Replace("]", @"\]").Replace("^", @"\^").Replace("-", @"\-")
        )
 );
 return Regex.Replace(propRegex, 
        $"[{regex}]+", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a positive lookahead subexpresión forcing the match to comply with a pattern like

```
(?=^[^yourcharlisthere]*$)
```

that anchors your string to beginning and end as all the characters must be absent from the matched string.

Or you can add a negative lookahead subexpression rejecting as soon as the string has one char in the list.

```
(?![yourcharlisthere])
```

this time you don't need to anchor, as as soon as one of the characters matches, the complete subexpression matches, and as such, your string is rejected.  Just add those at the beginning of you original regular expression.

Comment: So in your example I would do this? 
string returnThisString = propRegex + "(?![" + restrictedChars + "])";
return returnThisString;

Comment: sorry, but I don't know what language you are using to match the strings.... it seems that as factible... but just try it.  I'm not a c# expert (nor even novel)