# Pass old regular expression to new custom regular expression to exclude specific characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a program with a lot of string constants being used to allow specific characters via regular expressions. I now have a list of characters I want to block everywhere, but I don't want to have to go back through all my old string constants and rewrite them. Instead, I want to create a list of restricted characters and edit that list in only one place (in case it changes in the future). I'll then run all the string constants through a custom regular expression.

I have the list of restricted characters defined in web.config like so:

```
<add key="RestrChar" value="\!#%&lt;&gt;|&amp;;"/>
```

Calling a custom regular expression like this:

```
[RestrictCharRegExpress(ConstantStringName, ErrorMessage = CustomErrMsg)]
public string StringName
```

Class is defined as follows:

```
public class RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
   public RestrictCharRegExpressAttribute(string propRegex) : base(GetRegex(propRegex)){ }

   private static string GetRegex(string propRegex)
   {
        string restrictedChars = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RestrChar");
        return Regex.Replace(propRegex, $"[{restrictedChars}]+", "");
    }
}
```

Now this works when `ConstantStringName` specifically includes some of the characters I want to exclude like this:

```
public const string ConstantStringName = "^[-a-z A-Z.0-9/!&\"()]{1,40}$";
```

`!` and `&` are explicitly included so they will get replaced with nothing. But this won't work if the characters I'm trying to exclude aren't explicitly listed and are instead included via a list like this:

```
public const string ConstantStringName = "^[ -~\x0A\x0D]{1,40}$";
```

I've tried adding a negative lookahead like this:

```
return propRegex + "(?![" + restrictedChars + "])";
```

But that doesn't work in both cases. Also tried the negated set:

```
int i = propRegex.IndexOf(']');
if (i != -1)
{
    propRegex = propRegex.Insert(i, "[^" + restrictedChars + "]");
    return propRegex;
}
```

Still not working for both cases. Finally I tried character class subtraction:

```
int i = propRegex.IndexOf(']');
if (i != -1)
{
    propRegex = propRegex.Insert(i, "-[" + restrictedChars + "]");
    return propRegex;
}
```

And once again I achieved failure.

Does anyone have any other ideas how I can achieve my goal to exclude a set of characters no matter what set of regex rules are passed into my custom regular expression?

Comment: I can't see that any of the characters in `RestrChar` are included in `^[ -~\x0A\x0D]{1,40}$`, why do you assume that they would be removed?

Comment: @silkfire space through tilde is looking for a match in a range from char code 32 to 126. Exclamation point (!) is char code 33. The pound sign (#) is code 35. So yes I do believe some of the characters in RestrChar are included in that range.

Comment: What you mean to do is parsing the regex pattern, which is fraught with issues. The patterns  should be created manually or in a very specific way, say, with some placeholders that you could replace with some custom subpatterns.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OK cool thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually figured out what I'm trying to do:

```
int indexPropRegex = propRegex.IndexOf('^');
string restrictedCharsAction = "(?!.*[" + restricedChars + "]);
propRegex = indexPropRegex == -1 ? propRegex.Insert(0, restrictedCharsAction) : propRegex.Insert(indexPropRegex +1, restrictedCharsAction);
return propRegex;
```